# Issue with Elements in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am new to android programming and recently I had discovered that the many Images i had used in my app are resulting in OOM error and resulting in the crash of my app.So right away deleted the background and all the images of all the buttons and the layout without thinking any thing but later realized that all the elements have been out of their location and are confined into a single list of elements with a with very low width as shown in the below picture one below the other.

How i arranged them-

[image: Original elements location etc..]

How they look right now-

[image: How the elements became]

I tried to revert the whole project to a previous time including the images,that didn't work.I had done everything like completely formatting and installing android studios again that to didn't help at all.I had already faced these type of problem many times in android studios like if i drag an element in Relative layout sometimes,I would face a similar problem but that could be solved by a simple undo.But i coudn't do that this time.

So if any one knew what's is this problem with the elements in relative layout.Please help me out.
Thankyou.

Complete XML file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
android:paddingLeft="3dp"
android:paddingRight="3dp"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
tools:context="com.androgeekzz.pokemongo_bestguidetipsandtricks.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/blues">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/pokecover"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cover" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearla1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:weightSum="2">

<Button
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/basics"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="basicsOnclick"
    android:background="@drawable/pokebige" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/advGuide"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basics"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="advanceOnclick"
    android:background="@drawable/pokadva" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearla2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearla1"
        android:weightSum="2">

<Button
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/Tips"
    android:layout_below="@+id/basics"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="tipsOnclick"
    android:background="@drawable/pokettips" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/Tricks"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Tips"
    android:layout_below="@+id/advGuide"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:onClick="tricksOnclick"
    android:background="@drawable/poketrain" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearla3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearla2"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/Resources"
            android:layout_below="@+id/basics"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:onClick="resourceLinksOnclick"
            android:background="@drawable/pokeres" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/About"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Tips"
            android:layout_below="@+id/advGuide"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:onClick="aboutOnclick"
            android:background="@drawable/pokabout" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Share the layout xml. That should help.

Comment: shared it @Shaishav

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageView` in question appears fine to me. Since, its width is set as `wrap_content`, it'll be 0 as long as no image is set. But, if you supply any image to it, it should expand accordingly. Ideally, as it appeared to me, its width should be `match_parent` as the layout looked most consistent then.

I'd also suggest to use a `android:scaleType="center"` or `android:scaletype="centreCrop"` since, in the above image the aspect ratio doesn't appear to be ideal.

Comment: even setting the width too some no like 200DP also it is staying the same just tried it now @Shaishav

Comment: @PrudhviReddy With the EXACT file you provided to me, a 200dp width expands the view accordingly.

Comment: that is the problem with my project,it might work for you but there is some problem that is not confined with in the layout is my guess.I can't even resize it or do anything like assign a background for the activity etc..

Comment: @PrudhviReddy That is highly unlikely, its hard for me to believe that. But, I don't have any way of verifying this either :) .

Comment: Sry bro @Shaishav it might sound unlikely to believe to you but..This is surely true i coudn't say any thing more..Any way thanksfor your help..